# Nginx - upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, nginx, server

I have an issue with nginx that may be more complicated than it seems.
I have an application written in flask which works perfectly fine locally. I set it up on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I have an Nginx 1.10.3 installed and configured as proxy. Database is MongoDB v4.2.3 I have Gunicorn set up like in this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

The problem is, when I try to load data from mongo it tries to process the request for 30 seconds and then throws *502 Bad Gateway*. I looked into **nginx's error.log**:

`[error] 12361#12361: *28 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: example.com, request: "GET /example_route/view_database/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/user/flaskapp/src/application.sock:/example_route/view_database/", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/example_route"`

as for the **mongod.log**:

```
2020-04-09T22:18:29.534+0200 W  QUERY    [conn89] Plan executor error during distinct command: FAILURE, status: ClientDisconnect: operation was interrupted because a client disconnected, stats: { stage: "COLLSCAN", nReturned: 2745, executionTimeMillisEstimate: 24703, works: 2746, advanced: 2745, needTime: 1, needYield: 0, saveState: 1378, restoreState: 1377, isEOF: 0, direction: "forward", docsExamined: 2745 }
2020-04-09T22:18:29.534+0200 W  COMMAND  [conn89] Unable to gather storage statistics for a slow operation due to lock aquire timeout
2020-04-09T22:18:29.534+0200 I  COMMAND  [conn89] command db_name.col_name command: distinct { distinct: "elem", key: "some_key", lsid: { id: UUID("someid") }, $db: "db_name", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN numYields:1378 ok:0 errMsg:"Executor error during distinct command :: caused by :: operation was interrupted because a client disconnected" errName:ClientDisconnect errCode:279 reslen:202 locks:{ ReplicationStateTransition: { acquireCount: { w: 1379 } }, Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1379 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1378 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1378 } }, Mutex: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_msg 30475ms
2020-04-09T22:18:29.535+0200 I  NETWORK  [conn89] end connection 127.0.0.1:40296 (5 connections now open)
2020-04-09T22:18:29.614+0200 I  NETWORK  [conn88] end connection 127.0.0.1:40294 (4 connections now open)
2020-04-09T22:18:30.136+0200 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:40310 #96 (5 connections now open)
2020-04-09T22:18:30.137+0200 I  NETWORK  [conn96] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:40310 conn96: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.10.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "4.4.0-165-generic" }, platform: "CPython 3.5.2.final.0" }
2020-04-09T22:18:30.160+0200 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:40312 #97 (6 connections now open)
2020-04-09T22:18:30.160+0200 I  NETWORK  [conn97] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:40312 conn97: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.10.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "x86_64", version: "4.4.0-165-generic" }, platform: "CPython 3.5.2.final.0" }
```

Another thing is that when I try to upload data to the server (and upload is way more important for me) I get just a popup that is like:

```
example.com says

INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

No data in **nginx's error.log** about it. When I look into dev console in browser i just see:

```
POST http://example.com/example_route/send 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Both things work perfecty fine locally on my laptop.

nginx server configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        location /static {
                alias /home/user/flaskapp/src/app_here/static;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/flaskapp/src/application.sock;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 16400M;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
        }
}
```

Gunicorn process config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve flaskapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/flaskapp
Environment="PATH=/home/user/flaskapp/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/flaskapp/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:application.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

function that sends data to server in python:

```py
@main.route('/example_route/send', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def send():
    data = request.json
    new_data = Data_model(
        timestamp = data['Timestamp'],
        area = data["Area"],
        image = data["Image"]
    ).save()
    return redirect(url_for('main.data_viewer'))
```

and js on client side:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: '/example_route/send',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(sendDict),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
// success code
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.statusText);
        },
    });
```

as for readnig data from server is:

```py
@db_viewer.route('/example_route/view_database/')
@login_required
def view_database():
    data = Data.objects.only('UID').distinct('UID')
    return render_template('example_app/view_database.html', ids=data, user=current_user)
```

To sum up, there are 2 problems which bring nightmares and I just couldn't solve them:

- 500 internal server error when I try to send json data to server
- upstream error when I try to read from database

only being a problem on server, both working just fine locally.